# Get all children of children and so on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

I am using MongoDb as database.

I want all the children of children and so on. 
Lets Suppose

- A has B & C children
- B has D & E children
- D has F & G children

So when I query for children node **A**. I get all the children as output such as B C D E F G

```
 C = Customer.find_by(:id => "SOME_ID")
 C.children #list all children upto one level
```

So can anyone suggest me the way, to get recursive children.

Customer model

```
class Customer

  include Mongoid::Document
  field :email, type: String
  field :referral_id, type: String
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Customer',foreign_key: "referral_id", optional: true
  has_many :children, :class_name => 'Customer', :foreign_key => "referral_id"

end
```

Can anybody please help me out. Or suggest a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add a custom method to gather all the children of a customer, and children of children, and so on.

```
class Customer
  def descendants
    self.children | self.children.map(&:descendants).flatten
  end
end

cust = Customer.find(<id>)
cust.descendants
 => # Array of all the descendants of customer
```

Comment: Thanks man, you are life saviour.

Can you please explain what your code is actually doing. Its help me a lot

Comment: It iterates over `cust.children` and then recursively calls `descendents` on them, which returns their children, and call `descendents` on them, and so on.

Comment: can you please help me to modified this above function to find out the Nth level of child. Not all children, fetch Children upto Nth level.  

As I am trying to pass parameter to this method. but I got failed to use params in map and calling it recursively

Comment: That might take some time. Why don't you try on your own and if still cannot figure it out, ask a separate question so that others can help?

Comment: yeah sure. Thanks

Comment: thank you so much for this. this is exactly what I was looking for.