# Active record: how to recursively load children of children of children in one query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I need to load an object (organizations) and all its child organizations (and all its child organizations etc.) in one query- I then want to serialize the result as JSON.
Note: I'm using a logger to log all SQL queries to the console. (to count the number of queries)
`ActiveRecord::Base.connection.instance_variable_set :@logger, Logger.new(STDOUT)`

Currently I'm loading only the root parent organizations and then serializing the result. this lazy-loads each list of children with a new SQL query per child!

I've tried to solve this like so: `org.all.include(:children)` and `org.all.preload(:children)`- but this has 2 problems:

- When I try access the children I see rails makes another DB request anyways (even if I've 'preloaded' that list of children)
- If this worked, it would only load 1 level of children- I need it to load all children recursively

I've also viewed these other stack overflow articles- they dont solve the n+1 query problem: [Get all children of children and so on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51369739/get-all-children-of-children-and-so-on)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Which database? You're looking for a "recursive CTE".

Comment: mySql database- but I'm using active record- so the database should be irrelevant, right?

Comment: The database is never irrelevant, ActiveRecord doesn't do that much in the way of portability for anything non-trivial. Sorry, can't help with MySQL, you'd use `WITH RECURSIVE` with PostgreSQL, SQLite, SQL Server, ... but I don't know how to do a recursive query with MySQL.

Comment: I guess, this is gem will solve your problem
 https://github.com/ClosureTree/closure_tree

Not tried this gem practically, but after looking at it's documentation this may help you

Answer (score 1):

You can use [nested set pattern](https://github.com/collectiveidea/awesome_nested_set) for ActiveRecord models, This is very efficient pattern for load nested or recursive Tree data set.

```
gem 'awesome_nested_set'
```

#### Update your migration file following way:

```
class CreateOrganization < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :organization do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :parent_id, null: true, index: true
      t.integer :lft, null: false, index: true
      t.integer :rgt, null: false, index: true

      # optional fields
      t.integer :depth, null: false, default: 0
      t.integer :children_count, null: false, default: 0
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

#### Add nested functionality

Enable the nested set functionality by declaring `acts_as_nested_set` on your model

```
class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_nested_set
end
```

With the help of this gem you will efficiently load all of the child organizations record.

Learn More about [How Nested set model work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_set_model)